# Traefik kubernetes multiple SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, traefik

I am using Traefik like a reverse proxy on my Kubernetes cluster and I'm looking a way to use multiple SSL Certificates.

[According to the doc](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-tlsstore), is not possible to use multiple TLSStore, I must use only the `default` store.

For example, I have two domains `app1.com` and `app2.com` and two certificates for `*.app1.com` and `*.app2.com` known by Traefik using secret `app1-com-ssl` and `app2-com-ssl`, is it possible to store these two certificates in the same default TLSStore?

Here my **TLSStore** definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: TLSStore
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: app1

spec:
  defaultCertificate:
    secretName:  app1-com-ssl
```

Here my **IngressRoute** for `app1`:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: routes
  namespace: app1

spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
    - web

  routes:
  - match: Host(`test.app1.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: test-service
      port: 8080
  tls:
    store:
      name: default
```

Here my **IngressRoute** for `app2`:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: routes
  namespace: app2

spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
    - web

  routes:
  - match: Host(`test.app2.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: test-service
      port: 8080
  tls:
    store:
      name: default
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. The TLSStore doesn't currently support multiple certificates it just supports a *'default certificate'*. And as you have already seen you can only specify a *'default'* TLSStore.

The Traefik configs do allow you to [specify multiple certificates](https://docs.traefik.io/https/tls/#certificates-stores) for the *'default'* TLSStore (But not the K8s CRD) I have opened a [feature request](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/7210) for the Traekik TLSStore CRD to add support for multiple certificates.

✌️